# How to implement reference to another model in Relay Mutations on the server side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm stuck with Refs in Relay Mutation and globalIdField.

So let's say that comment can have parent comment id, must have post id in props and I have a Mutation defined with following schema:

```
const createComment = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'CreateComment',
  description: 'Create comment of the post',
  inputFields: {
    content: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      description: 'Content of the comment',
    },
    parent: {
      type: GraphQLID,
      description: 'Parent of the comment',
    },
    post: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
      description: 'Post of the comment',
    },
  },
  outputFields: {
    comment: { type: commentType, resolve: comment => comment },
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: (input, context) => (context.user
    ? Comment.create(Object.assign(input, { author: context.user._id }))
    : new Error('Only logged in user can create new comment')),
});
```

My comment has globalIdField, postType too. When I will query mutation from client I will use everywhere globalIds instead of real mongo _id of this objects. Is here the better way for it instead this piece in mutateAndGetPayload:

```
mutateAndGetPayload: (input, context) => {
  if (input.parent) input.parent = fromGlobalId(input.parent).id;
  if (input.post) input.post = fromGlobalId(input.post).id;
  // And other logic
}
```

It can be very convinient if I can just add globalIdField() in post, but Relay can't pass this, because field in inputFields can't have a resolver function which globalIdField has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I can't find solution better than below:

```
mutateAndGetPayload: ({ content, post, parent }, context) => {
    if (!context.user) throw new Error('Only logged in user can create new comment');
    const newComment = { author: context.user._id, content };
    if (post) newComment.post = fromGlobalId(post).id;
    if (parent) newComment.parent = fromGlobalId(parent).id;
    return Comment.create(newComment);
  },
```

Would be so glad if somebody will provide better experience with this.